# Visual studio Paste without moving cursor to the end

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to paste some string in visual studio via some shortcut or other extension to keep the cursor where it is after the paste?

This way if I add multiple words of string I will not have to go with the cursor back to the location via ctrl-arrows or home key when I don't want the cursor to go to the end of pasted text.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644926/visual-studio-cursor-position-after-pasting

Comment: Thanks @SergeyVlasov - I have resharper already installed and will stick with it - yet the solution you provided is definitely an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way to do it with resharper - if any better suggestions out there please feel free to answer.

Create a simple template as

```
$END$$CopiedContent$
```

and set the CopiedContent variable to clipboard content.  Give it a shortcut vc (ctrl-v inverted) - and have fun. It will require an extra left arrow and escape char to get desired effect.

It costs VC[TAB][Left_ARROW][ESCAPE] meaning 5 characters which is more than I originally wanted. Willing to trade for a better answer.